# MsSql Filtering expanding tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

## MsSql Filtering expanding tables

tags: sql-server sql

To keep it basic: There are 2 tables, one is just an extension of the other:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNiZg.jpg)

As Table 2 is an extension, I'm using a left join.
Everything's working fine - however, filtering columns of Table 2 causes issues.

Code to rebuild the example:

```
create table Table1
( idUnique int)

create table TableExtension
(
idUnique int,
someInfoID int
)

insert into Table1
Values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)

insert into TableExtension values (2,2)

select a.idUnique, someInfoID
from Table1 a
left join TableExtension b on a.idUnique=b.idUnique

select a.idUnique, someInfoID
from Table1 a
left join TableExtension b on a.idUnique=b.idUnique
where someInfoID = isnull(null,someInfoID)

select a.idUnique, someInfoID
from Table1 a
left join TableExtension b on a.idUnique=b.idUnique
and someInfoID=isnull(2,someInfoID)
```

The second Select-query should select all data but only shows data that's also existing in Table2. However, the third query should only show the row 2-2 (currently showing all)

I know, that filtering for nulls is done by using 'is' but how can it be connected with the "isnull" function? (the function is needed since I use it for potential filtering - i.e.

```
Column=ISNULL(@Filtervariable,Column))
```

Does anyone of you have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Use IS to check for null, not =. Your ISNULL() or COALESCE() will evaluate to null for records in which no value exists. (NULL = NULL) Is False. You need to add an additional null check in your statement.

Comment: The ISNULL function is used in order to be able to filter. Structure:  Column=ISNULL(@FilterVariable,Column).  Therefore it is necessary and I cannot use the 'is' operator

Comment: In that case you could simply compare for null in in conjunction with comparing for equality --> WHERE(@FilterVariable=Column OR @FilterVariable IS NULL).

Comment: @Ross Bush that's working fine! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

The NULL is not a data type but a condition of the data type. You can use it as a data type. According to Microsoft documentation

> To test for null values in a query, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL in the
>   WHERE clause.

to read more: [Null values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx)